# NPM declaring variable in path.js using dotenv and environemnt file

Tags: npm, git-branch, dotenv

I am trying to automatically add my homepage using .env file based on the branch I am in using "gitBranchIs". Its working correctly but I am having hard time assigning a variable to inside my path.js

```
var gitBranchIs = require('git-branch-is');
require('dotenv').config()
      const envPublicUrl = gitBranchIs('master', function (err, result) {
      if (result) {

        return process.env.PUBLIC_NON_PRD_URL;
      } else {
        return process.env.PUBLIC_NON_PRD_URL;
      }
    })

console.log("BILLY", process.env.PUBLIC_NON_PRD_URL) // THIS IS RETURNING CORRECT URL FROM MY .ENV FILE
console.log("BILLY", envPublicUrl ) this return undefined
```

Any one why when I return the value in "envPublicUrl" it returns 'undefine'. I even tried using arrow function but still same

Comment: I think the problem is 'gitBranchIs' async

Answer (score 1):

I change library and use "getCurrentBranchName" instead